# Get Dailymotion video player status

Tags: dailymotion-api

is there any API method that help me get the video status of Dailymotion video player? I know on the old Dailymotion document:

http://www.dailymotion.com/en/doc/api/player-deprecated/javascript_api#DailymotionPlayerTools-playing-a-video

There is a player.getPlayerState() method that would help me solve this case. But I don't think that method work on the latest Dailymotion version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`player.getPlayerState()` is not exposed within the latest DM player (consistency reasons). Instead, you can use [player-events](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#player-api-events) : Below some examples :

```
// old
player.getPlayerState() // playing, pause, ended

// new
player.addEventListener('playing', function(e){});
player.addEventListener('pause', function(e){});
player.addEventListener('ended', function(e){});
```